# Are ifstream/ofstream really used for serialization?

Tags: c++, string, file-io, stl, stream

I am using ifstream and and ostream to serialize my data but I am surprised to discover the `<<' operator can't seperate two adjacent strings and seperating them would be quite complicated.

```
class Name
{
string first_name;
string last name;


friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Name& _name)
{
     os << _name.first_name << _name.last_name; 
     return os;
}

friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, Name& _name)
{
     is >> _name.first_name >> _name.last_name;

     return is;
}
```

This doesn't work because << and >> doesn't write null terminator characters and ifstream reads the whole string in variable (first_name) which is kinda disappointing. How can I store the two strings separately so I can read them separately as well? I don't understand what is the motivation of `<<` concatenating all the strings in ostream so we can't read them back seperatly!?

Comment: You should probably separate the values by spaces.

Comment: Well, you've opened them in text mode and not binary mode, so why would it write a null terminator? That's a binary detail.

Comment: iostreams by themselves are not built specifically for serialization, but for generic IO (and `operator<<` in particular for text based IO). You should probably use a serialization library to handle the field separation details and stuff.

Comment: @GManNickG: since when opening a file in binary mode added a null terminator in the output of `operator<<(const std::string &)`? AFAIK it just affects the translation of newlines.

Comment: @Matteo : I think GMan was also implying to use unformatted writes instead of `operator<<`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yeah, I made that less clear/too implicative. My goal was that you should you use binary mode [whereupon you use unformatted writes], when you want binary details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times you want to concatenate strings with `ostream` (commonly `stringstream`). If you specifically don't want them concatenated it's easy enough to do:

`os << _name.first_name << '\n' << _name.last_name;`

Comment: Yeah, I concatenate strings all the time with `ostringstream`. It's really cool to be able to concatenate strings with other types as well, the kinds of cases where you can't use `+` for concatenation. e.g.: `os << string_var << int_var`. It may not be useful in the OPs use case, but it is useful in many others.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand what is the motivation of << concatenating all the strings in ostream so we can't read them back seperatly!?

This assumes that the *only* reason to write them separately is to read them as individual strings. Consider the case where someone has a pair of strings that they want to write to a stream *without* separators. Or a string followed by a float that they don't want separators for.

If `ostream`s automatically inserted separators for every `<<` output, then it would be much harder for someone to write text *without* separators. They'd have to manually concatenate these strings and/or values into a single string, then output that.

And what would they use for this concatenation? They can't use `ostringstream` like you normally might, because it uses the same facilities as `ofstream`. So every `<<` would put a separator character in the stream.

In short, the IO streams API writes what you *told it* to write, not what you may or may not "want" to write. It's not a serialization API; C++ isn't C# or Java. If you want serious serialization features, use [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/).

Answer (score 1):

`ifstream` and `ofstream` basically are streams, so they have nothing to indicate limit of data in them. Think about them as a river, all data can read from or write to them. This is true nature of files, so if you need them for serialization you must implement your serialization mechanism or use a library that designed for this purpose like `boost::serialization`. In C++ every thing implemented as is, and because of this you can gain maximum performance!! :)